# Mascara para dinheiro em android

Tags: java, android, mask

Estou criando uma função para quando o usuário digitar em um `EditText` , ele me retorne com uma masca no campo,

Exemplo:

- Ao digitar 1 retorna "R$ 0.01"
- Ao digitar 11 retorna "R$ 0.11" e
  assim por diante

Tentei desta maneira

```
  public static String addMask(final String textoAFormatar) {
        String formatado = "";
        int i = 0;

        if (textoAFormatar.length() == 1) {
            String mask = "R$ #.##";
            DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            String texto = format.format(textoAFormatar);


            // vamos iterar a mascara, para descobrir quais caracteres vamos adicionar e quando...
            for (char m : mask.toCharArray()) {
                if (m != '#') { // se não for um #, vamos colocar o caracter informado na máscara
                    formatado += m;
                    continue;
                }
                // Senão colocamos o valor que será formatado
                try {
                    formatado += texto.charAt(i);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }

        }


        return formatado;
    }
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nessa library](https://github.com/faranjit/currency_edittext), utilizo ela e funciona certinho pra esse problema.

Comment: @RogersMarques, por favor, peço que leia os guias para iniciantes do SO, principalmente o [tópico sobre os comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), no ponto de quando se deve ou não fazer comentários.

Comment: @RogersMarques , o StarkOverflow serve para isso, procurar profissionais que nos ajude com nossos problemas de iniciante

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática perfeito, funcionou perfeito no projeto !!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Utilize a classe [NumberFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) para resolver este seu problema. É uma classe do próprio SDK e é bem fácil de ser utilizada.

Uso:

```
String money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(0.01);
```

Retorno:

```
R$ 0,01
```

O método `getCurrencyInstance()` retorna a moeda local do dispositivo. Se o dispositivo estiver usando um local `EN`, a moeda retornada será **USD**.

Answer (score 1):

Não realizei todos os testes possíveis, mas acredito que uma das formas de resolver o seu problema seja assim:

```
String str = textoAFormatar; // argumento da sua funcao

if (str.length() == 1) {
    str = "00" + str;
} else if (str.length() == 2) {
    str = "0" + str;
}   

int index = str.length() - 2;
return "R$" + str.substring(0, index) + "." + str.substring(index);
```

Além disso, imagino que o mesmo resultado pode ser alcançado com [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).